# Correlation analysis for binary variables in R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, correlation

```
dat <- as.data.frame(replicate(100,sample(c(0,1),100,replace=TRUE)))
```

I want to create a 100 by 100 matrix with the correlation coefficients between these binary variables as entries.

If the variables were continuous, then I would have used `cor()` to create the matrix. I am not sure if `cor()` with Pearson as the method is reasonable. If not, say I could find a function `fn()` to calculate the correlation between a pair of binary vectors. What is an efficient way to construct the 100 by 100 matrix?

Comment: What are the binary variables? ie could they represent some underlying normally distributed latent variable?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure this is a stack overflow answer. What you are asking is for the correlation between binary vectors. This is called the [Phi coefficient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) which was discovered by Pearson.

It approximates the Pearson correlation for small values. You might try

```
sqrt(chisq.test(table(dat[,1],dat[,2]), correct=FALSE)$statistic/length(dat[,1]))
```

and notice that it gives the same value `0.08006408` as

```
cor(dat[1], dat[2])
```

This is because the approximation is quite good for reasonably large values, say greater than 40.

So, I would advocate saving yourself some time and just using `cor(dat)` as the solution.

Comment: is phi just a case of pearson?

Comment: Yes, just in the case of a 2x2 contingency table. Otherwise, they are not in the same range.